# Read timeout connecting to server on Docker container

Tags: docker, db2-luw, docker-network, wsl-2, windows-defender

I'm trying to connect to a DB/2 container (image: ibmcom/db2) but it gives me a read timeout error. The host OS is Windows 10. I can see the port (50000) in the Windows PowerShell prompt, but it gives me a read timeout.

I've added an inbound Windows Defender rule to allow all local ports and an output rule to allow all remote ports. I have this regardless of the program. I realize this is not a good practice, but I'm trying to rule out a firewall issue. Despite this, it still gives me a read timeout error. I added more specific rules earlier, but they naturally did not help.

I also started an SSH server in that container and could log into it from within the container, but not outside of it. When connecting from outside, I got the same read timeout message. I do *not* feel this is a db2 issue.

Having said that, I was able to get sickp/alpine-sshd:7.5-r2 and  gists/lighttpd to come start and be accessible from the host. That is, I can see the web default web page for lighttpd and log into the SSHD server for alpine-sshd. Both of these work with no appreciable delay. This worked before making the above firewall adjustments.

I'm convinced that somehow, this container is not working for me. Other people have tried the exact same docker run that I provide below, and it comes up for them.

I'm using Win 10, WSL2. Docker version 20.10.7, build f0df350.

I start the container by doing:

```
docker run -itd --name mydb-db2 \
                --privileged=true \
        -p 50000:50000 \
        -e LICENSE=accept \
        -e B2INSTANCE=db2inst1 \
        -e DB2INST1_PASSWORD=<mypassword> \
        -e DBNAME=MYDB \
        -e TO_CREATE_SAMPLEDB=false \
        -v db2:/database \
        ibmcom/db2
```

Netstat evidence:

```
C:\Software>netstat /a /n |grep 50000
  TCP    0.0.0.0:50000          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:50000             [::]:0                 LISTENING
```

Attempt to connect to jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/MYDB
on host system results in "Read timed out. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001"

Docker container status:

```
~/projects-new/db2$ docker container ls
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE        COMMAND                  CREATED      STATUS          PORTS
                                              NAMES
110aa19976dd   ibmcom/db2   "/var/db2_setup/lib/…"   2 days ago   Up 28 minutes   22/tcp, 55000/tcp, 60006-60007/tcp, 0.0.0.0:50000->50000/tcp, :::50000->50000/tcp   mydb-db2
```

Inspection of container:

```
~/projects-new/db2$ docker container inspect 110aa
[
    {
        "Id": "110aa19976ddb53d16eac9376476f974fee8e9c699da3f76c1e2e13c444655c2",
        "Created": "2021-07-16T04:10:51.1247765Z",
        "Path": "/var/db2_setup/lib/setup_db2_instance.sh",
        "Args": [],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 5459,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2021-07-18T03:56:45.0493495Z",
            "FinishedAt": "2021-07-18T03:54:18.4239523Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:a6a5ee354fb1242a75d508982041cd48883f3fe7c9c9b485be0da6c0ebd44a39",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/110aa19976ddb53d16eac9376476f974fee8e9c699da3f76c1e2e13c444655c2/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/110aa19976ddb53d16eac9376476f974fee8e9c699da3f76c1e2e13c444655c2/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/110aa19976ddb53d16eac9376476f974fee8e9c699da3f76c1e2e13c444655c2/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/110aa19976ddb53d16eac9376476f974fee8e9c699da3f76c1e2e13c444655c2/110aa19976ddb53d16eac9376476f974fee8e9c699da3f76c1e2e13c444655c2-json.log",
        "Name": "/mydb-db2",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [
                "db2:/database"
            ],
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "default",
            "PortBindings": {
                "50000/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "50000"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "no",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "CgroupnsMode": "host",
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "private",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": true,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": [
                "label=disable"
            ],
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": [],
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DeviceRequests": null,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "KernelMemoryTCP": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": null,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": null,
            "ReadonlyPaths": null
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b6ecb6d5e949ab8e58d9238e34878a563a45f5045d57c684e5a08b6ec833ebb4-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6cf25bf1ac29315c3832316ef32b1cae8cf1ed6e71e4ddd9d08ab5566f81da9e/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/76ca13571a6d253356b48ac20b408d33f80c5e6b429c132533e60c7578e99fb3/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e1a78196ef6f70929701e708904cb2696189c37a40839a0f20407148d2d90f1d/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/efa2b4a3bc7e7411a671f05ad9121a4bb609452560b5f73d4b765e8519bfa36d/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/933425814e17216adcfcac390e789c6dfc8ada12ded902db2ca9a542a5ff555c/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/2ec2f25d859b77fd93a16468e40de569c41b35055c58277ad97d839cb33a01ac/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/62aeaecc9fea67541671d95f691a2d8ddc9076ee0ae3bc96cd3b030a3ecc663b/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f04ce4e91dedc0c14073e43734ca252a7c0bd6f6ed9ab89f77d6797f72312f2d/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/21b929e594040a64ffb0cd2c8bd4d3d7f630a3ec3dd79e8157c41c0d9783faa6/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c5e235fc2e9dc254394bcae472264b133530f5dfbb285cfe5f0ba0dac26ce4c4/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/8f68a8bb1e9ca565aa1d8debc221bb498512a6ed24cc07bcf3ef07c8c42e045f/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/745a0aa01d1a904ce08c22d07be527cdb39da0c37b87a66a57062cc307ca4d4c/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f0a873fda45d17a036833dd0dc9362f02b0ab00c590f23bf38ba59d06c624272/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b6ecb6d5e949ab8e58d9238e34878a563a45f5045d57c684e5a08b6ec833ebb4/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b6ecb6d5e949ab8e58d9238e34878a563a45f5045d57c684e5a08b6ec833ebb4/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b6ecb6d5e949ab8e58d9238e34878a563a45f5045d57c684e5a08b6ec833ebb4/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "db2",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/db2/_data",
                "Destination": "/database",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "z",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            },
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "47c06e44c75f70947a907a0972924536761f70f15971459e8be6015b29e2e48c",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/47c06e44c75f70947a907a0972924536761f70f15971459e8be6015b29e2e48c/_data",
                "Destination": "/hadr",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "110aa19976dd",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "22/tcp": {},
                "50000/tcp": {},
                "55000/tcp": {},
                "60006/tcp": {},
                "60007/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": true,
            "OpenStdin": true,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "LICENSE=accept",
                "B2INSTANCE=db2inst1",
                "DB2INST1_PASSWORD=<mypassword>",
                "DBNAME=BLUECOST",
                "TO_CREATE_SAMPLEDB=false",
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "container=oci",
                "STORAGE_DIR=/database",
                "HADR_SHARED_DIR=/hadr",
                "DBPORT=50000",
                "TSPORT=55000",
                "SETUPDIR=/var/db2_setup",
                "SETUPAREA=/tmp/setup",
                "NOTVISIBLE=in users profile",
                "LICENSE_NAME=db2dec.lic"
            ],
            "Cmd": null,
            "Image": "ibmcom/db2",
            "Volumes": {
                "/database": {},
                "/hadr": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "/var/db2_setup/lib/setup_db2_instance.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "architecture": "x86_64",
                "build-date": "2021-06-01T05:31:45.840349",
                "com.redhat.build-host": "cpt-1007.osbs.prod.upshift.rdu2.redhat.com",
                "com.redhat.component": "ubi7-container",
                "com.redhat.license_terms": "https://www.redhat.com/en/about/red-hat-end-user-license-agreements#UBI",
                "description": "The Universal Base Image is designed and engineered to be the base layer for all of your containerized applications, middleware and utilities. This base image is freely redistributable, but Red Hat only supports Red Hat technologies through subscriptions for Red Hat products. This image is maintained by Red Hat and updated regularly.",
                "desktop.docker.io/wsl-distro": "Ubuntu-20.04",
                "distribution-scope": "public",
                "io.k8s.description": "The Universal Base Image is designed and engineered to be the base layer for all of your containerized applications, middleware and utilities. This base image is freely redistributable, but Red Hat only supports Red Hat technologies through subscriptions for Red Hat products. This image is maintained by Red Hat and updated regularly.",
                "io.k8s.display-name": "Red Hat Universal Base Image 7",
                "io.openshift.tags": "base rhel7",
                "name": "ubi7",
                "release": "405",
                "summary": "Provides the latest release of the Red Hat Universal Base Image 7.",
                "url": "https://access.redhat.com/containers/#/registry.access.redhat.com/ubi7/images/7.9-405",
                "vcs-ref": "a4e710a688a6374670ecdd56637c3f683d11cbe3",
                "vcs-type": "git",
                "vendor": "Red Hat, Inc.",
                "version": "7.9"
            }
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "570856178f99951c7cdfccc638a3404f906a7a89905ba9d39181cd9310f4380b",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "22/tcp": null,
                "50000/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "50000"
                    },
                    {
                        "HostIp": "::",
                        "HostPort": "50000"
                    }
                ],
                "55000/tcp": null,
                "60006/tcp": null,
                "60007/tcp": null
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/570856178f99",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "a50d8643af88c0d677a9dc2d889f20ab909f46707bb7bd0f8168666b18d1b414",
            "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "408fe3a7130f9791810b8668b60b7f90478f4673f79270539044362e8c12d88f",
                    "EndpointID": "a50d8643af88c0d677a9dc2d889f20ab909f46707bb7bd0f8168666b18d1b414",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

I didn't see the db2 container listed. These are my networks:

```
C:\Software>docker network ls
NETWORK ID     NAME                             DRIVER    SCOPE
408fe3a7130f   bridge                           bridge    local
38fc17e8e6f1   cirrus-ssc-file-sender_default   bridge    local
1668ab71959f   host                             host      local
4bf4f6b3a57e   minikube                         bridge    local
e07fc0032414   none                             null      local
```

Instead, I found it on the bridge network.

I'm not trying to do anything fancy. I'd really rather it run on the same network host. If the host system can "see" the exposed port of 50000 via Netstat, wouldn't that mean it's not a firewall issue?

Update: I turned off Windows Defender and it still does not work.

Update 2: I hosted the same container on a different machine but on my home network. When I try to connect to it from the problem machine, it gives me the same read timeout error. However, it *works* from the hosting machine. Somehow there seems to be a problem between this particular Windows machine and this particular container.

Update 3: SVCENAME info:
I ran the following inside the db2 container:

```
$su db2inst1 (when I log in it goes to root)
$cd ~
$. ./.bashrc
$db2 get dbm cfg |grep SVCENAME
TCP/IP Service name                          (SVCENAME) = db2c_db2inst1
 SSL service name                         (SSL_SVCENAME) =
$grep dbc2_db2inst1 /etc/services
db2c_db2inst1      50000/tcp
db2c_db2inst1_ssl  50001/tcp
```

DB2 Container OS Version info:

```
$ cat /etc/*release
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
VERSION="7.9 (Maipo)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VARIANT="Server"
VARIANT_ID="server"
VERSION_ID="7.9"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.9 (Maipo)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.9:GA:server"
HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"

REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.9
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7.9"
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.9 (Maipo)
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.9 (Maipo)
```

WSL Linux version used:

```
$ cat /etc/*release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

Windows version info of the host system (from winver):
Windows 10
Version 21H1 (OS Build 19043.1110)

Computer successfully connecting to DB/2 container:

```
$ cat /etc/*release
Fedora release 30 (Thirty)
NAME=Fedora
VERSION="30 (Workstation Edition)"
ID=fedora
VERSION_ID=30
VERSION_CODENAME=""
PLATFORM_ID="platform:f30"
PRETTY_NAME="Fedora 30 (Workstation Edition)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;34"
LOGO=fedora-logo-icon
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:fedoraproject:fedora:30"
HOME_URL="https://fedoraproject.org/"
DOCUMENTATION_URL="https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/f30/system-administrators-guide/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Communicating_and_getting_help"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Fedora"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=30
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Fedora"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION=30
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Legal:PrivacyPolicy"
VARIANT="Workstation Edition"
VARIANT_ID=workstation
Fedora release 30 (Thirty)
Fedora release 30 (Thirty)
```

Comment: Would this be an inbound or outbound rule? Why would a blocked port show up in netstat?

Comment: A couple of clarifications - *"I'm trying to connect"*.  Are you trying to connect from the Windows host itself or from another machine on the network?  Given the mention of firewall rules, I'm assuming the later, but want to confirm.  *"Other people have tried the exact same docker run"*.  Are they using WSL or a Linux host?

Comment: the current (july 2021) ibmcom/db2 seems to run RHEL 7.9. Not sure if that plays well with WSL2.  There is currently a line in the docs for "Docker Desktop for Windows" that states __Docker Desktop for Windows can’t route traffic to Linux containers. However, you can ping the Windows containers.__

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I'm trying to connect from the windows host. The recent tester was on some version of MacOS. However, this *has* worked before on Windows.

Comment: @mao I would have favored your comment as it makes the most sense. Someone decided to upgrade something in the latest version. I previously had been using something that was 8 months old, but when I tried it again, it gave me the same error.

Comment: Does it work without the WSL2 back-end (i.e. with the Hyper-V back end instead). ?

Comment: @mao I'm not sure how to check this.

Comment: @Woodsman, you need to mention the differences between the working machine and failing machine, (e.g. both using same winver build number, same docker version, same edition of windows, same wsl2 etc). Also please confirm that on the failing machine that the db2inst1 really is using 50000 port by using the commands that i listed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235191/discussion-between-woodsman-and-mao).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your symptom might be caused by some machine specific configuration, or some downlevel component (in particular WSL2).

On my hardware, at the current date, with current version of WSL2, ibmcom/db2 accepts connections from the local MS-Windows host (via jdbc )  with the following mix of components:

- MS-Windows 10 Pro build 19043 (21H1) x64
- the latest build of the "Linux WSL2 kernel package for x64 machines"
- Docker Desktop 3.5.2 configured to use WSL2

However, with a previous mix of configurations , I recreated your failure symptom with WSL2, i.e. jdbc connection attempt from local MSWindows host into the linux container gave sqlcode -4499 (in my case reply.fill() insufficient data).

The failing combination was:

- MS-Windows 10 Pro build 19041 x64.
- older build of "Linux WSL2 kernel package for x64 machines" (downloaded before 22/July/2021)
- Docker Desktop 3.5.2 configured for WSL2

With the previous failing combination, only WSL2 back end recreated your symptom, but the Hyper-V back end worked correctly.

With Docker-Desktop on a Win10PRO environment, right click on its icon, choose Settings, and it lets you tick (or untick) "Use WSL2 based engine", click Apply and Restart. You may get other notifications. You may lose your containers and images and need to download them again so if you need to preserve any data then arrange that separately before changing the back end.

If you cannot make progress via upgrading components, then a re-install  or image may be an option.